How do I store data from a file into two lists?
I need to read data from a file game.txt and append the data into two lists. The first list should hold the player's name and the second list should hold the high score.
Also, this is for school and I'm not allowed to use split method, dictionaries, or with statements.
The game.txt file is a list of names and scores that looks like this:
John\n
7\n
Mary\n
5\n
Larry\n
9\n
Mark\n
4\n

def read_file():
    infile = open(FILENAME, 'r')
    line = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')
    while line != '':
        for item in FILENAME:
            player_names.append(line)
            high_scores.append(line)
            line = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')
    infile.close()


Can you provide an example of the desired behavior: an input file, and what lists you expect from it?  And why you iterate over the letters of the file's name?

What does the input file look like? It is just lines of name, score, name, score... etc?

We cannot answer this question, because you have not shown us an example of the data in game.txt.

for item in FILENAME: What is the purpose of this loop?  FILENAME is just a string, so this will loop over each character in the filename.  Why are you doing that?  Also, you never use the result variable item, so this loop is doubly useless.

"not allowed to use with statements" is like saying "I want to cook but I'm not allowed to wash my hands" - it's not strictly needed for the task but it's a good practice.

Are you trying to show that the file contains names and scores in alternating lines? Or that each line contains a name and a score?

Why are you not allowed to use split, dict or with? That's ridiculous. They are an integral part of the language and, given that that's apparently what you're learning, you should be using them where appropriate.

You can read two lines at a time, and store them as the name and score.
def parse_scores(filename):
    player_names = []
    high_scores = []

    file = open(filename, "r")
    try:
        while (
            name := file.readline().strip()
        ) and (
            score := file.readline().strip()
        ):
            player_names.append(name)
            high_scores.append(int(score))
    finally:
        file.close()

    return player_names, high_scores


def main():
    player_names, high_scores = parse_scores("game.txt")
    print("Player Names:", player_names)
    print("High Scores:", high_scores)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This assumes that game.txt is in the following format:
John
7
Mary
5
Larry
9
Mark
4

The program output should be:
Player Names: ['John', 'Mary', 'Larry', 'Mark']
High Scores: [7, 5, 9, 4]

Alternative
The more pythonic or idiomatic alternative would be to use splitlines() and then take alternating slices.
def parse_scores(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
        player_names = lines[::2]
        high_scores = list(map(int, lines[1::2]))

    return player_names, high_scores


def main():
    player_names, high_scores = parse_scores("game.txt")
    print(f"Player Names: {player_names}")
    print(f"High Scores: {high_scores}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


how can you be so sure this is the answer, when OP have yet to provide with a sample file?

Thanks this helps. My inelegant attempt at this was to make a temporary list, append everything into the temporary list, and then try to slice the names out using a start, stop, step, and then do that again with the scores. But I have also been having trouble figuring out how to have the length of the temporary list be the stopping point for my slice.

The question shows that the file contents are, for example, John\n 7\n Mary\n 5\n Larry\n 9\n Mark\n 4\n. i.e., lines alternating by name/score. If that's the case then this code will not work.

@SIGHUP I responded prior to the provided input. I have updated the response to reflect the provided input format.

The question states that the input file contents are, for example, "John\n 7\n Mary\n 5\n Larry\n 9\n Mark\n 4\n"
In other words, it has alternating lines of name / score.
That being the case and given the (slightly bizarre) restrictions, I suggest:
FILENAME = "foo.txt"

names = []
scores = []

def get_name_and_score():
    data = open(FILENAME)
    while name := data.readline().strip():
        score = int(data.readline())
        yield name, score
    data.close()

for name, score in get_name_and_score():
    names.append(name)
    scores.append(score)

print(names)
print(scores)

Output:
['John', 'Mary', 'Larry', 'Mark']
[7, 5, 9, 4]


Iterating over pairs like this is well-supported by a common zip trick to get all complete batches of size n:
def read_file():
    with open(FILENAME, 'r') as infile:  # Use with statements, get guaranteed deterministic close
        for name, score in zip(*[map(str.strip, infile)]*2):
            player_names.append(name)
            high_scores.append(score)  # Change to .append(int(score)) if conversion desired

This works by making a single-pass iterator (files are already single-pass, and even if they weren't, wrapping in map(str.strip, ...) to eliminate leading/trailing whitespace as we go would do so), putting it in a list, repeating it n times (in this case, two times), then unpacking it as arguments to zip. zip pulls from each argument once for each tuple it returns, and since you passed the same argument n times, that means it reads n lines from the same file.
More Pythonically, you'd receive the file name as an argument, and return the two lists as return values (constant global state isn't the worst, but it's less reusable; mutable global state is a nightmare for reentrancy, repeated calls, etc.). And if you wanted to get fancy, zip can take the pairs that zip itself produced, and convert them to two sequences (as tuples, not lists, but conversion back to list is trivial if you care):
def read_file(filename):  # Receive filename as argument
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:  # Use with statements, get guaranteed deterministic close
        return zip(*zip(*[map(str.strip, infile)]*2))

        # Or replace the return line to convert the scores to int and return true lists
        names, scores = zip(*zip(*[map(str.strip, infile)]*2))
        return list(names), [int(score) for score in scores]
        # Or for maximum efficiency, but a more obscure:
        # return [*names], [*map(int, scores)]

zip(*...) here is passing each of the pairs to zip as an argument, causing it to zip all of the first elements of the pairs together, then all the second elements, producing names and scores directly. They begin as tuples, but converting a tuple to a list is highly optimized, and if we want to convert the scores to int anyway, a listcomp will convert them and produce a true list at the same time.
